# Line to feature from label in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: labeling, arcgis-pro

I want to have a line from each label to the features it labels. I am trying to a label a lot of features in a small space and need it to be clear which label coresponds to which feaure.

How can I achieve this in ArcGIS Pro 2.3?

Comment: I'd check the help for terms like callout and leader line.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thank you. The line callout was what I was looking for.